# jQuery animate callbacks firing out of sequence

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, jquery-callback

I am creating a UI component in which a target element, when clicked, sets off a sequence of animation. The animation is supposed to happen in sequence: click the target element(targetEl), a transparent overlay fades over the target element(overlay), another div slides down over the overlay(slideover), the slideover has a close icon, when the close icon is clicked the previous animation happens in reverse (slideover slides up, overlay fades out).

My issue is this: I am using nested .on("click") and animation calls. The animation works perfectly for the first few clicks but then behaves strangely on about the 3rd or 4th click. The overlay will fade in/out quickly and you won't see the slideover animate at all. I think what is happening is that the animation is somehow getting out of sequence.

Here is my JS/jQuery:

```
$(targetEl).on("click", function() {

     $(overlay).on("click", function(e){e.stopPropagation();});

     $(overlay).fadeIn("slow", function(){
         $(slideover).animate({"top":targetEl.height()/3}, 1000);
     });

     $("#close").on("click", function(e){
          e.stopPropagation();

          $(slideover).animate( {
                "top":'-'+targetEl.height()/3}, 1000, function({
                         $(overlay).fadeOut("slow");
                });
          });
      });
```

I use stopPropagation where I do because slideover is a child of overlay, which is a child of targetEl and I didn't want clicks on the children to "fall through" to the parent element. 
Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Every time you are animating based on the (targetEL) click, you are binding new events to the overlay click, and the #close element.

That might be the reason why it's seeming so strange.

Do those bindings **prior** to the targetEL click triggering.